# Why call intrinsicContentSize function when intrinsic size is set in Interface Builder already?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview, interface-builder, ios-autolayout

In the Apple Guide to Swift Programming, in the chapter ["Implement a Custom Control"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1), I first set the intrinsic size of the custom view in Interface Builder,

[image: screenshot of description to add intrinsic size in IB]

but later, the Guide tells me to call the `intrinsicContentSize` function in the custom class:
 [image: call intrinsicContentSize again]

Is it necessary to implement both the `intrinsicContentSize` method as well as specify the intrinsic Size in Interface Builder, or is it a redundant step, meaning just one of either steps is sufficient for the interface to work properly?

Answer (score 2):

The `CGSize` returned from the method `intrinsicContentSize` is the actual intrinsicContentSize of your custom view.

Because the returned value of the `intrinsicContentSize` function is only determined at runtime, the interface builder needs some placeholder values to visualize the UI. Without entering those placeholder values into the interface builder, you may get some warnings about missing constrains. However, whatever you enter will be used as a placeholder only, the `CGSize` returned from the method `intrinsicContentSize` is still the actual value used when the app runs, the value entered into the interface builder is ignored.

Xcode (7.3.1) displays an explanation as below when you change the Intrinsic Size to Placeholder:
[image]